# How can I start the "speaking" in preview with key?

Tags: macos, preview, voiceover

I want my Mac to read things out in preview, now I have to click on Edit --> Speech --> Start speaking. How can I use keys/shortcuts to start it? I use MacOS BigSur 11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1: Use VoiceOver

From [Apple Support: Have your Mac speak text that’s on the screen](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/have-your-mac-speak-text-thats-on-the-screen-mh27448/mac):

> On your Mac, press the specified keyboard shortcut (the default key combination is Option-Esc).
> If text is selected when you press the keyboard shortcut, the selected text is spoken.

### Method 2: Add a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences to trigger menu the command

If you *specifically* need to trigger the menu command, you can create a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences. Here's the process:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select “Keyboard” then open the “Shortcuts” tab
3. Select “App Shortcuts” from the sidebar
4. Create a new entry by clicking the “+” button

More detailed instructions can be found at [Apple Support: Create keyboard shortcuts for apps on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac)

#### Screenshots

[image: system preferences showing process of adding a keyboard shortcut]
[image: system preferences showing added shortcut]